# Как реализовать резкое движение игрока(прыжок прямо) и прилипание п поверхности, пол, стены потолок в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Как реализовать резкое движение игрока(прыжок прямо) и прилипание п поверхности, пол, стены потолок в Unity?
Чтобы этот кубик например прилипал к поверхностям, примерно я понимаю что это можно с помощью колизии сделать, но примеров не нашел! 
В каком хотябы направлении копать?
Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: конкретизируйте вопрос - 2d/3d? приведите, возможно, примеры из других игр, демонстрирующих желаемое движение. Покажите, что у вас уже есть и что вы пытались сделать

Comment: @vmchar на скриншоте явно 2д. :)

Answer (score 2):

Вот эта строка задает вектор гравитации для всех обьектов на сцене.

```
Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, -1.0F, 0);
```

В случае с таким вот тэстовым проэктом на 1 обьект этого может быть вполне достаточно.

В ином случае нужно гуглить что-то вроде `unity local gravity 2d` или `localized physics unity 2d` и, уверен, что кто-то уже решал подобную задачу.

Comment: Попробую! Спасибо!